# Does only Rohloff manufacture the sprocket for their Speedhub 14?

Tags: internally-geared-hub, replacement, sprocket, rohloff

Are there any manufacturers other than Rohloff who make the sprocket for the Rohloff Speedhub 14?

Is the sprocket Rohloff specific or is it a standard / general / everyday part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the email reply from Rohloff customer support

> It is always possible that parts are copied. To ensure warranty and reliability, we advise against buying copied parts. Especially because the  hardness of the metal of the sprocket is important.